# Why does my virtual machine stop conducting blueprism automated processes when I minimize or close it?

Tags: process, automation, blueprism, rpa

I automate processes on a remote computer. When I start a process from the control room, that works totally fine. But as soon as I minimize or close the remote computer (I don't shut it down, I just close the window), the remote computer crashes. The log contains entries like that elements cannot be found. The reason is, that the remote computer does not even open the applications.

So, what's the reason for that? The computers state is on desktop, so there is no screensaver or logon screen.

Expected result: The robot should work finely even when the remote desktop session is not on screen, like in production environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified, but the below answer extrapolates your statements regarding how you've "[minimized] or [closed]" your "remote computer" to assume you're leveraging Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection utility/protocol.

Blue Prism specifically discourages the use of Remote Desktop to manipulate remote Runtime Resources within a Blue Prism-based environment, as the use of the protocol itself causes the methodologies Blue Prism uses to locate elements in the Windows desktop environment to stop working entirely. This is explicitly spelled out in [Blue Prism's official documentation on Remote Access Tools](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2017-11/v6%20Data%20Sheet%20-%20Remote%20Access%20Tools.pdf):

> The following tools have been deemed to be **specifically unsuitable** for
>   providing remote access to Blue Prism environments:
>
> - **Remote Desktop Connection (RDP)**
>     The way that this Windows tool (and other tools that
>     use the RDP protocol) handle session management is not compatible with
>     Blue Prism:
>
>   - The underlying operating system is aware as a connection is established which can, subject to the automation techniques being
>       applied, result in the executing automation being interupted.
>   - It requires the remote access credentials to be aligned with the credentials used to authenticate the target system against the network
>       which presents a potential security risk.
>   - As a user authenticates any previously connected users are locked out.
>   - Each connection creates a separate desktop session.
>   - The connection is not maintained throughout a system reboot.